# Correctly splitting by string with Parsec

Tags: haskell, parsec

The code below outputs `Right ["1<!>2<!>3"]`, but I need `Right ["1", "2", "3"]`.

```
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec

response = contents :: CharParser () [String]
  where
    contents = sepBy content contentDelimiter
    contentDelimiter = string "<!>"
    content = many anyChar

main = do
  putStrLn $ show $ parse response "Response" "1<!>2<!>3"
```

I suppose the problem here is that the `content` parser consumes all the input before `sepBy` gets to test the delimiter. So, my questions are:

1. Am I correct with my assumption? If not, what is the mistake I've made?
2. What solution would you recommend for such a problem? (Using Parsec)

*** `content` has to match any string not containing the delimiter. The `1<!>2<!>3` is just an example it can be `dslkf\n><!>dsf<!>3` or whatever

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For your first example, you would replace

```
content = many anyChar
```

with

```
content = many digit
```

So that the parser of the content doesn't erroneously match the separator.

Maybe you want to match more than just digits but even so, I advise you to think carefully about what *is* valid between `<!>`s and write a parser that does that.

**Why?**
Once you've got a really good parser for content, your definition for response will be perfect. This way your content can include `mystring = "hello<!>mum"` without being chopped by the top level parser - the low level `stringLiteral` parser will eat the whole `"hello<!>mum"` and the top level parser will never see the `<!>` correctly and innocently included inside it.

**Generally,...**
In most parsing situations it's best to be really clear what's allowed in your content, and parse only that, for three reasons:

- reusability (you can then use this within a larger parser)
- correctness
- usually efficiency - if you avoid too much lookahead, your parser runs faster.

Reusability is important. At the moment, if you use a parser that just splits on `<!>` and eats everything else, it's guaranteed to eat the whole input, and you won't be able to do any more parsing.

**Bottom-up**
Your parsers should work from the ground up - you described this very well in your comment as "stacking the parsers from specific to general".

It's easiest to write them in that order for ease of testing, so first write one that matches a `stringChar` then `stringLiteral` before `member` before `array` before `object` before `json` before `content` then `response`. You can have them calling each other recursively along the way. You can then use `parseTest` to test each little one as you do along; typing `parseTest response "1<!>2<!>3"` into ghci is quicker than rewriting main and compiling.

**Top-down?**
It's not wrong to write your parser top-down, just harder. You can write

```
response = many $ content `sepBy` contentSeparator
content = json <|> somethingElse
json = object <|> array
array = ...
```

but nothing is testable until you've written the very smallest parser.

Comment: The point here is I need content to match any string except the one containing the delimiter

Comment: @NikitaVolkov Are you sure that's what you mean? `"1  $& {-not a comment-}\n <<<<<%><!><!>\nrt"` is valid and should parse as `["1  $& {-not a comment-}\n <<<<<%>","","\nrt"]`? Be sure what you want in your items.

Comment: The effiency remark on lookahead is helpful. Still the "1<!>2<!>3" thing is just an example. Actually I'm parsing a dirty server response, which can contain any characters, and the only thing that's stable is the delimiter

Comment: @NikitaVolkov and once you've split it into those things, you're done parsing? There's no more parsing of the individual items?

Comment: Of course not. There'll be some complex parsing, which I couldn't include in the question: for instance an extraction of JSON for some parts, for other parts there'll be other parsers. Yeah I get your point now: I have to reverse my approach by stacking the parsers from specific to general. Thanks! Right? )

Comment: Absolutely - write the smallest parsers, then build up to big ones. Once you've got a really good parser for `content`, your definition for response will be perfect. This way your content can include `mystring = "hello<!>mum"` without being chopped by the top level parser - the low level `stringLiteral` parser will eat the whole `"hello<!>mum"` and the top level parser will never see the `<!>` correctly and innocently included inside it.

Comment: Well, that last point of yours was a killer. A correct parser should expect the "<!>" to be possible inside, for instance, a value in JSON. Yeah. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a solution using `noneOf`, provided that neither '<' and '!', nor '>' are part of your content.

```
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec

response = contents :: CharParser () [String]
 where
   contents = sepBy content contentDelimiter
   contentDelimiter = string "<!>"
   content = many (noneOf ['<','!','>']) 

main = print $ parse response "Response" "1<!>2<!>3"
```

Comment: Sorry but same as with the answer by AndrewC, I need content to match any string except the one containing the delimiter